# how to print multi digit numbers in x86 ? do we wriite a manual print routine or we create an itoa function? which is a better implementation and how?

Tags: assembly, printing, x86, integer, nasm

consider a statement like

```
print(12345);
```

How would something like this be done in assembly?

I've read that we could try to move through the number right to left , pushing the digits onto the stack one by one , and once we have traversed the entire number , we would pop the digits from the stack one by one and then define a print routine which would print just a digit ,and then call it for every pop.

Would it be easier to define an itoa function ? Anyways how to implement either of the approach?

Comment: After having done both you will know which one was easier :)

Comment: If you know the theoretical maximum value, you can also do it left-to-right by dividing first by 10,000 (assuming a 16-bit number), then 1,000, and so on, and then suppressing leading zeroes as you go.

Comment: @500: That algorithm either requires a table of powers of 10 to descend through, or requires two divisions per iteration.  And you need to find the right power of 10 to start with to not print leading zeros if you don't want them.  Since you're printing, presumably that means a `write` system call or something else that can take a pointer+length, so you can just store into a buffer in descending order.  When you're done, you have a pointer to the first digit which you can pass to `write` or `puts` or whatever, or manually copy to append to your own larger buffer. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @aryan04: Using stack push/pop is one strategy to get the characters in printing order (MSD first), but only one character at a time.  Only appropriate for systems where you can't efficiently write a whole string.  Unless you store those `pop` results back to memory again, in which case you're copying the data around an extra time for little benefit: a small `memcpy` can line up the data to the start of a buffer if necessary if you store it contiguously in the first place (as in the linked duplicate), and it's cheaper not to be expanding each byte to a 4-byte or 8-byte stack slot.

Comment: @PeterCordes Nitpick: `memcpy` in standard C is not allowed to operate on buffers that may overlap. Of course in assembly you'd do it using a small move loop either with `rep movsb` or equivalent, and if you move forwards (Direction Flag UP) the overlap is okay as long as the destination is below-or-equal the source.

Comment: @ecm: Good point.  I was mostly thinking about using a scratch buffer on the stack if you need the final value lined up somewhere else, but yeah `memmove` to move bytes within a buffer.  But if you can write bytes after (but not before) it, like when growing a buffer and you're going to store other stuff after, `mov rax, [rdi]` or `movdqu xmm0, [rdi]` to load 8 or 16 bytes (or 2 regs for 2x), then store (possibly overlapping).  Looping 1 byte at a time would be terrible, and `rep movsb` has significant startup overhead even on CPUs with the "fast short REP" feature compared to a 1-vector copy.

Comment: (The store-forwarding stall from doing a wide load after narrow stores isn't great, but it can pipeline with fast-path store-forwarding in surrounding code, and OoO exec can hide the latency.)